# Uniform Continuity of $1/x^3$ on compact intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

So, I have the function $f : (0,\infty) \to \Bbb R$. With $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ and I have to show that $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on the set $[1,\infty)$. Is the following proof correct?

$[1,\infty) = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} [n,n+1]$. And each of those sets is compact, and $f(x)$ is continuous so by Heine-Cantor it is UC on every compact set, and thus it is UC on the whole union of them.

Is this coherent/consistent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knowing that it is uniformly continuous on a sequence of compact sets isn't sufficient to know that it is uniformly continuous on their union. Consider the fact that $$(0,\infty)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac1n,n+1\right]$$ with your given function to see why not.

I recommend proceeding in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ fashion, instead. Since your function gets less and less steep as you move to the right, it should suffice to find a $\delta$ that works in $[1,2],$ and show that it actually works everywhere in $[1,\infty).$

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the point about the union of compact sets

Comment: @user1190931 By the way, the reason you can take unions for plain old continuity is that continuity on an interval just requires continuity at each point, and each point in the union belongs to one of the intervals.  By contrast, *uniform* continuity on an interval demands bounds that work for that entire interval.  Just having bounds within each interval does not allow you to bound the entire union at once.

Answer (score 4):

$[1,\infty)$ is not compact!

I suggest a workaround without Heine–Cantor as follows: A sufficient condition for uniform continuity is that

> $f$ is differentiable, $|f'|$ is bounded.

Then (hover the mouse below to see the spoiler)

> $$|f(x) - f(y)| = \Bigg|\displaystyle \int^y_x f'(t)dt\Bigg|\leq \int^y_x |f'(t)|dt \leq M|x-y|.$$

Comment: MVT could also be used.  (This would avoid the mild additional hypothesis that $f'$ is integrable.)

Comment: Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

If $f:[a,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous function such that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Proof sketch: Given $\varepsilon>0$, choose $M>a$ such that $|f(x)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ when $x>M$. Then choose $\delta>0$, $\delta<1$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$ and $x$ and $y$ are in the compact interval $[a,M+1]$.  It follows that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$ and $x$ and $y$ are in $[a,\infty)$.

---

But for this particular function, you could just play around with $\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\dfrac{1}{y^2}$ to see why it is uniformly continuous, and even Lipschitz.  E.g., $$\left|\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\dfrac{1}{y^2}\right|=\left|\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{y}\right|\left(\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{y}\right)\leq \dfrac{|y-x|}{xy}\left(\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{y}\right).$$  See what happens when you use $x,y\geq 1$?

**Added**: I just noticed that I got $\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ from the body of the question, but the title says $\dfrac{1}{x^3}$.  I might not update my answer even if the latter is intended, but a similar approach (slightly more complicated) would apply.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!